# Is the phrase "back to the Muggle world" an adjective or adverbial one?

Tags: adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases

> People jostled them as they moved forward toward the gateway **back to
>   the Muggle world**. (Harry Potter)

Is the phrase "back to the Muggle world" an adjective or adverbial one?

Comment: It's an adjectival phrase- It describes the gateway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you choose to interpret the sentence. Suppose I add a comma:

> People jostled them as they moved forward toward the gateway, back to the Muggle world.

Then it seems pretty clear it's ***adverbially*** modifying *moved*.

Without the comma, it's pedantic to say *back to the Muggle world* can ***only*** be ***adjectivally*** modifying *the gateway*. No comma just makes that a *possible* (or *likely*, depending on your point of view) reading.

So the answer is - take you pick. It can be either (or *both*, if you're a "creative" reader).

Comment: Yours is what I was thinking about. But I couldn’t put down it, having worried to say silly nonsense. Now, I’m very pleased to be backed by good explanation.

Comment: And you gave me an idea that ‘back to the Muggle world’ can be thought as a complement for ‘they.’ Thank you.

Comment: @Listenever: I've no idea how you manage to see it as a "complement" for "they", but if it helps you to understand the sentence elements and their relationships, [fill your boots](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fill%20your%20boots). Me, I can only see an indirect relationship. Basically, they *moved*. The rest is just more details about that movement, not directly about *them*.

Comment: ...if you're determined to find a "complement", you might consider *as they moved forward toward the gateway, back to the Muggle world* as a candidate, defining "them" in more detail.

Comment: Um.. then, my thought against the definition of complement, I need to look the sentence over again. Thank you.: I've read today 6 times the book, and tomorrow I'm going to start 7 times. When I get other thought later, i'll ask again.

Comment: Is there no possibility to see ‘back to the Muggle world’ as like a participial phrase to modify ‘they’? Like the participial phrase of following case: “The clumsy man looked awkward trying to carry the large suitcase.”

Comment: Or can ‘back to the Muggle world’ be meaning, “and they came back to the Muggle world”?

Comment: If all can't be possible, when a comma is put in front of 'back,' then, could it be meaning, "and they came back to the Muggle world”?

Comment: @Listenever: It's useful to distinguish *adverb/adjective* here because that governs whether BTTMW modifies *moved* or *gateway* (not that it really affects the overall meaning). But I don't see how you stand to gain a greater understanding from any other terminology being bandied about here. Basically, *People jostled them*, which is expanded by *[them] as they moved forward*, itself expanded by *[forward] toward the gateway*. The only interesting thing is what does *came back to the Muggle world* "attach" to, and as I've said, you can choose between the two possibilities. That's all there is

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "back to the Muggle world" modifies "gateway", which is a noun.  It does not modify the verb "moved".  So, given your two choices, I would pick "adjective", not "adverbial".